# git: pushing through socks5 proxy with ProxyCommand+ncat fails

Tags: ssh, git, socks-proxy, socks5

socks5 proxy runs as follows

```
ss-local ... -l 1080 ...
```

pushing w/ proxychains suceeds

```
$ proxychains git push
```

```
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/libproxychains4.so
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] Strict chain  ...  127.0.0.1:1080  ...  github.com:22  ...  OK
Warning: the RSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address '224.0.0.1'
Offending key for IP in /home/darren/.ssh/known_hosts:40
Matching host key in /home/darren/.ssh/known_hosts:2
Everything up-to-date
```

**pushing w/ ProxyCommand+ncat fails**

```
$ env GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv -o ProxyCommand='ncat -vvvv --proxy-type socks5 --proxy 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p'" /usr/bin/git push
```

```
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/darren/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/darren/.ssh/config line 4: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/darren/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/darren/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ncat -vvvv --proxy-type socks5 --proxy 127.0.0.1:1080 github.com 22
debug1: identity file /home/darren/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/darren/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
Ncat: Version 7.91 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
libnsock nsock_set_loglevel(): Set log level to DEBUG
NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /usr/share/ncat/ca-bundle.crt.
Ncat: Connected to proxy 127.0.0.1:1080
Ncat: No authentication needed.
Ncat: Host github.com will be resolved by the proxy.
Ncat: connection succeeded.
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_iod_new2(): nsock_iod_new (IOD #2)
libnsock nsock_loop(): nsock_loop() started (no timeout). 0 events pending
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.
libnsock nsock_iod_delete(): nsock_iod_delete (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_iod_delete(): nsock_iod_delete (IOD #2)
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

Info

```
$ uname -r
5.10.4-arch2-1
$ pacman -Qii proxychains-ng | grep Version
Version         : 4.14-2
$ git --version
git version 2.30.0
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
$ ncat --version
Ncat: Version 7.91 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
```

~/.ssh/config

```
...
Host github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
...
```

/etc/proxychains.conf

```
strict_chain
proxy_dns 
remote_dns_subnet 224
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
[ProxyList]
socks5 127.0.0.1 1080
```

Comment: workaround - [use netcat from openbsd instead of nmap](https://mijazz.icu/posts/ssh-proxycommand-nc-error/)

Comment: bug [#2149](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/2149) [#2280](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/2280)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it said in comments, it's a bug in `ncat`. It's fixed in `master`, but current version of macOS's homebrew still contains an old version.

For me compiling `master` from the [nmap repo](https://github.com/nmap/nmap) (and using the produced binary) fixed the issue.

**UPD**. Nmap (and ncat) just got updated to 7.92 in Homebrew, it works fine, and there is no more need to compile it.

```
❯ ncat --version
Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
```